# Using FocusNode in TextFormField Flutter

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `TextFormField` that is supposed to receive digits. On entry of first digit it should jump to second `TextFormField` then to the third TextFormField. Each `TextFormField` has the `FocusNode` property I just do not know how to use it. I have this

```
TextFormField(     //First Field                            
     autofocus: true,
     focusNode: FocusNode(),
     decoration: InputDecoration(
     border: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0)
      ),
      ),
     style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.orange,
      fontSize: 15.0,
      ),
     keyboardType:
      TextInputType.number,
     maxLength: 1,
      ),

    // second Field
   TextFormField(),

    //third Field
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I believe this is more or less what you are trying to achieve:

[image]

```
void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: PassCodeExample()));
}

class PassCodeExample extends StatelessWidget {
  FocusNode f1 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode f2 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode f3 = FocusNode();
  FocusNode f4 = FocusNode();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: f1,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (String newVal) {
                      if (newVal.length == 1) {
                        f1.unfocus();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(f2);
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: f2,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (String newVal) {
                      if (newVal.length == 1) {
                        f2.unfocus();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(f3);
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: f3,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    onChanged: (String newVal) {
                      if (newVal.length == 1) {
                        f3.unfocus();
                        FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(f4);
                      }
                    },
                    decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: TextField(
                    focusNode: f4,
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(border: OutlineInputBorder()),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can achieve the same by using `onSubmitted` or even supplying a unique `TextEditingController` to your `TextField`s

Comment: `onSubmitted` is called when the user clicks on the submit button the keyboard, however when are using pass code you do not want the user to click on the submit button, but instead detect if the user has entered one character in each text field, hence what you need is `onChanged`

Comment: Got it. Check out another question I have posted about 'how to save values from the textfield'. I am unable to retrieve the values of the TextField

Comment: I answered you there, you just assigned sth to newVal instead of assigning newVal to sth

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time the issue will be fixed if you place your Textfield/TextFormField as child of Form.