# How to shift focus to the next TextField in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, focus, textfield

I am new to Flutter.

I am building a form with multiple text inputs using following widgets: Form, TextFormField. The keyboard that appears doesn't show "next" (which should shift the focus to next field) field action instead it is "done" action (which hides the keyborad).

I looked for any hints in official docs, found nothing directly that can be done.
I although landed on FocusNode([cookbook](https://flutter.io/cookbook/forms/focus/), [api doc](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FocusNode-class.html)). It provides with mechanism to shift focus by some button or any other action on app, but I want it to be in **keyboard**.

Comment: also in flutter_gallery it is the same. there should be some mechanism though.

Comment: It's not possible as of now(see https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/11344). Which part of flutter_gallery are you talking about?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51909798/using-focusnode-in-textformfield-flutter/51910285#51910285

Comment: ohh, i need to find a work around. I meant the flutter_gallery has the same issue.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

Found a way to achieve it.

1. Displaying Next Icon instead of Done - setting `textInputAction` parameter to `TextInputAction.next`
2. Using `onFieldSubmitted` callback to request focus node of next field.

   ```
   class FormWidget extends StatelessWidget{    
      final focus = FocusNode();
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return Form(
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
           padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
           child: Column(
             crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
             children: <Widget>[
               TextFormField(
                 textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                 autofocus: true,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Input 1"),
                 onFieldSubmitted: (v){
                   FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);
                 },
               ),
               TextFormField(
                 focusNode: focus,
                 decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: "Input 2"),
               ),
             ],
           ),
         ),
       );
     }
   }
   ```

Edit: As stated in the documentation (flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/focus), - we also need to manage FocusNode lifecycle. So, init FocusNode in the init() method and dispose in dispose() of the parent Widget. - @AntonDerevyanko

Update: The same can be achieved without `FocusNode` and `FocusScopeNode`, by simply calling `FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus()`, take a look at [CopsOnRoad solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455958/6618622) on how to do that. For more info check [doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode/nextFocus.html).

Comment: As stated in the documentation (https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/forms/focus), - we also need to manage FocusNode lifecycle. So, init FocusNode in the init() method and dispose in dispose() of the parent Widget.

Comment: @Harsh what if there are more than two TextFormFields? 6 maybe

Comment: @fajarainul The logic remain the same. `onFieldSubmitted` of second field you `requestFocus` of third field

Comment: This solution has a bug. If you press tab, then tab not only changes focus, but is added to as text to the form field - this is not normal behavior for a form. Tab should change focus, or enter text, never both.

Comment: Instead of `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);` you can simply call `focus.requestFocus()`

Answer (score 316):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

Just use:

**`textInputAction: TextInputAction.next`**: To move the cursor to the next field.

**`textInputAction: TextInputAction.done`**: To close the keyboard.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'TextField A'),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, // Moves focus to next.
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'TextField B'),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, // Moves focus to next.
        ),
        TextField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'TextField C'),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done, // Hides the keyboard.
        ),
      ],
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: this still requires you to click the done button to focus to next input. how about auto focus. auto move to next field?

Comment: @Yuhao You can do that too using `onChanged` property.

Comment: InputDatePickerFormField doesn't implement the textInputAction :/

Comment: `nextFocus()` will not work if you use "Password hide/show button" next to TextField.

Comment: Useful answer, I used only textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, and it worked

Answer (score 35):

These are additional steps to [CopsOnRoad](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455958/6618622) answer since it doesn't work in more complex UI when there are focusable widgets in between text fields, for example:

- when the password field has a clickable toggle icon
- when there is a button (or some other focusable widget) between fields...

the solution here is to keep calling 'nextFocus()' until 'EditableText' is found

```
   @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField A"),
              textInputAction: textInputAction1,
              onSubmitted: (_) => context.nextEditableTextFocus(), // move focus to next
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField B"),
              textInputAction: textInputAction2,
              onSubmitted: (_) => context.nextEditableTextFocus(), // move focus to next
            ),
            MaterialButton(
             onPressed: () {},
             color: Colors.amber,
            ),
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "TextField C"),
              textInputAction: textInputAction3,
              onSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(), // submit and hide keyboard
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

---

Where the extension method is:

```
extension Utility on BuildContext {
  void nextEditableTextFocus() {
    do {
      FocusScope.of(this).nextFocus();
    } while (FocusScope.of(this).focusedChild?.context?.widget is! EditableText);
  }
}
```

Comment: this almost worked, I had to replace `onSubmitted: (_)` with `onEditingComplete: ()` to make it work with a more difficult layout

Comment: Spent almost 3 hours looking into this issue.
Thank you for this. 
Login form never had the issue as email field has no icon and password with the button was set to unfocus but when doing my password reset with old and 2 new password fields standard focusNext would close keyboard every time until I found this.

Answer (score 15):

**For TextFormFeild use can use onFieldSubmitted**

```
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Username"),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(), // focus to next
        ),
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(), // Unfocus and hide keyboard
        ),
```

**Don't know the exact reason but onFieldSubmitted sometimes skips one or more fields in that case onEditingComplete works as expected**

```
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Username"),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
          onEditingComplete : (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(), // focus to next
        ),
TextFormField(
          decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Password"),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
          onEditingComplete : (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(), // Unfocus and hide keyboard
        ),
```

Comment: It skips fields because `TextInputAction.next` alone causes the focus to shift

Comment: textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                              // onFieldSubmitted: (_) =>
                              //     FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),

  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next, it's enough to shifting the focus. No need of onFieldSubmit.

Answer (score 12):

For me this worked it moves to next input on entering first digit

```
Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onChanged: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                          controller:c1 ,)
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onChanged: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                          controller:c2 ,),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                          controller:c3 ,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onChanged: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                          controller:c4 ,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onChanged: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(

                          controller:c5 ,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onChanged: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 20.0,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                      child: TextFormField(
                          controller:c6 ,
                        textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                        onChanged: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).unfocus(),
                          ),
                    )
                  ],
                )
```

Comment: I used your code to set textfield next to each other, I am beginner in flutter. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Thanks for the extension shared by @haytham-anmar and the extension from @natesh-bhat!

But this will not work anymore for the future release of Flutter due to a breaking change on `EditableText` tree (ref.: [Move text editing Actions to EditableTextState #90684](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/90684)).

**Please consider the following migration code:**

*Before migration:*

```dart
extension Utility on BuildContext {
  void nextEditableTextFocus() {
    do {
      FocusScope.of(this).nextFocus();
    } while (FocusScope.of(this).focusedChild?.context?.widget is! EditableText);
  }
}
```

*After migration:*

```dart
extension Utility on BuildContext {
  void nextEditableTextFocus() {
    do {
      FocusScope.of(this).nextFocus();
    } while (FocusScope.of(this).focusedChild!.context == null);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried by adding just the `textInputAction`property, and it worked without anything else.

Maybe newer versions of Flutter have improved this functionality?
Or StatefulWidget & FormKey are needed to have this working?

I'm on Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5)

Give it a try:

```dart
class MyForm extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State createState() => _myFormState();
}

class _myFormState extends State<MyForm> {
  //
  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextFormField(
            // *** Just added this
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Input 1',
            ),
          ),
          TextFormField(
            textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              labelText: 'Input 2',
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You are right, I think it has been fixed [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/63575). Actually it is now an error to call `nextFocus` if you have set `textInputAction` to `TextInputAction.next`, it would cause skipping one field. So that was a breaking change.

Comment: I don't know, the return key-different action setting exists since many years (more than 10 in iOS). But I cannot tell you the same about Flutter support, maybe the behaviour has been "mapped" recently. 
Anyway, as long as one doesn't need particular behaviours, I would stick to using textInputAction, as it the default for an application, and users are accustomed to that :)

Answer (score 5):

In the latest flutter version, All the above ways do not work if you have a visible icon or any other icon in your form field. You can use this way to make it work

Create FocusNode for each of your TextFormFields, assign it to the TextFormFields and onEditingComplete, request focus to the next Node.

````dart
  FocusNode textFieldOne = FocusNode();
  FocusNode textFieldTwo = FocusNode();

  // ...

  TextFormField(
        onChanged: (_) {
           textFieldTwo.requestFocus();
        },
        focusNode: textFieldOne,
        controller: textController,
  )```
````

Answer (score 2):

I used
`onSubmitted` instead of `onFieldSubmitted`

Example code

```
      TextField(
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
                onSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
                controller: _phoneController,
                decoration: const InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Phone number',
                ),
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
              ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this helper function to focus the next text field :

```
void focusNextTextField(BuildContext context) {
  do {
    var foundFocusNode = FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
    if (!foundFocusNode) return;
  } while (FocusScope.of(context).focusedChild.context.widget is! EditableText);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I hope it's useful

```
textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        onEditingComplete: () {
             FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
        },
        onSubmitted: (value) {
            if (value.isNotEmpty) {
                  FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
            }
        },
```