# textInputAction: TextInputAction.next failing to move user focus to next element

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use TextInputAction and set it to next, the button does change on my simulator device however it doesn't do anything, User interaction is not moved into the next element.
Have opened a ticket on the FLutter `gitHUb page as well as in the chat rooms but no help so far and would like to keep the ball rolling on my training :)

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/47749

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to shift focus to next textfield in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150677/how-to-shift-focus-to-next-textfield-in-flutter)

Comment: I believe I am already doing what is suggusted with `FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focus);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is bug in your code , you put `_passwordFocusNode` in `email` field and cause error 
when `_emailEditingComplete()` , focus stay in email

```
void _emailEditingComplete() {
    FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
}

return TextField(
  controller: _passwordController,
  focusNode: _emailFocusNode,

return TextField(
  controller: _emailController,
  focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
```

`onEditingComplete` and `onSubmitted` both work correctly in this case

working demo for test

[image]

full test code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  final TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode _emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _passwordFocusNode = FocusNode();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    _emailFocusNode.dispose();
    _passwordFocusNode.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              focusNode: _emailFocusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Email',
                hintText: 'test@test.com',
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onEditingComplete: () {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
              },
              onSubmitted: (val) {
                //FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_passwordFocusNode);
              },
            ),
            TextField(
              focusNode: _passwordFocusNode,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'password',
              ),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
              onSubmitted: (val) {},
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

bug

[image]

Comment: You sir are a gentleman for taking the time and effort to debug that. I owe you a beer or lunch at the very least. Send me your paypal.me link to my uername without the same to Gmail