# Not show Next button in the soft keyboard

Tags: android, flutter

android studio 3.6

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    logger.d("build:");
    //String _errorMessage = null;
    return Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: new Text('Sign in',
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold))),
        body: new Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN,
                right: Constants.DEFAULT_MARGIN),
            child: new Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: new Column(children: [
                  new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
                      keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _email = value;
                        });
                      }),
                  new TextFormField(
                      decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Password'),
                      obscureText: true,
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _password = value;
                        });
                      })
                ]))));
  }
```

Here result:

[image]

The focus is on first field text (email). But on soft keyboard not show **Next** button (green button). Show **Done** button.
Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `textInputAction` property and assign `TextInputAction.next` enum to it. This will display the next button on the keyboard. FocusScope will allow you to change the keyboard focus. Here I just used [nextFocus()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FocusNode/nextFocus.html) to change the keyboard focus to the next TextFormField when pressing the next button.

```
TextFormField( 
  ...
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  onFieldSubmitted: (value){
    FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus();
  }
  ...
)
```

For more `textInputAction` types, please have a look at this [TextInputAction documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputAction-class.html)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify the `textInputAction` property to get that behaviour.

```
TextFormField(
   decoration: new InputDecoration(hintText: 'Email'),
   keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
   textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
   onChanged: (value) {
      setState(() {
         _email = value;
      });
   }
)
```

Refer [TextInputAction](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/TextInputAction-class.html) for all the available types

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna see next button in the keyboard should

```
TextFormField( 
  ...
  textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
  ...
)
```

But this alone will not focus on next input field.

Please check: https://medium.com/flutterpub/flutter-keyboard-actions-and-next-focus-field-3260dc4c694
or [How to shift focus to next textfield in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150677/how-to-shift-focus-to-next-textfield-in-flutter)