# FocusScope.nextFocus() unexpectedly skips one or more TextFormFields

Tags: flutter, focus

I would like to have a series of `TextFormField`s that the user can navigate by pressing "next" on the soft keyboard (or by pressing tab on the hard keyboard, when testing on an emulator). I was expecting the following Flutter app to work:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TextFormField Problem Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Test Homepage'),
      ),
      body: Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          onFieldSubmitted: (_) => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        ),
      ]),
    );
  }
}
```

... But pressing tab (on DartPad) or pressing "next" (on the soft keyboard of an emulator) jumps to a seemingly random field, instead of jumping to the next one. More specifically, it looks like `FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus()` "skips" one field (or more fields, sometimes, depending on the run) instead of just going to the next field.

I was assuming that `nextFocus()` can automatically figure out what is the next focusable widget among the children of my `Column`, even without explicitly having to specify the `focusNode` property of my `TextFormField`s (as seen in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60455958/3272066) on StackOverflow). Why is this not the case? Thank you for any input.

I am using Flutter 1.22 on an Android emulator (and on Dartpad).

Comment: I also started facing this issue. Surprisingly, I haven't made any changes to my codebase, just updated Flutter to 1.22 and this started to happen.

Comment: Same here. The update to 1.22 was the only thing that changed in my case too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flutter 1.22 includes a change to automatically advance the focus when you use textInputAction: TextInputAction.next. However, they didn't update the documentation.

If you specify both onFieldSubmitted and textInputAction, it does not work because it has the effect of calling nextFocus twice. So, the Flutter change was a breaking change.

You don't need to specify the onEditingComplete callback and handle it manually. Just TextInputAction.next is enough by itself.

The relevant Flutter change is [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/63592). Also, some discussion [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68571#issuecomment-716856038).

Note in the description of the Flutter change it says, "Focus will be moved automatically if onEditingComplete is not specified, but must
by moved manually if onEditingComplete is specified."

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer and for the links. Trying to only set `textInputAction` on DartPad (currently running Flutter 1.23) unfortunately still shows the same problem. I will try the same on an Android emulator as soon as I can. Moreover, as stated in the question, the number of fields that are "skipped" is unfortunately not just 1, but a seemingly random number: could it be that there is another, different problem from the one you are mentioning?

Comment: @Giorgio I tested the solution on both Android and iOS emulators, and it works for me. According to the Flutter engineer, it will skip just 1 field when you specify both. For example, see here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68571#issuecomment-716835454

And here: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/68571#issuecomment-716867536

Comment: He did say "roughly equivalent to calling nextFocus() twice", so maybe roughly is a clue that it won't always behave the same way. Just a guess, I haven't checked the Flutter source code.

Comment: Thaaaank you for the hint!

Answer (score 2):

`onEditingComplete()` should work in your case, not sure why `onSubmitted()` not working it should be working, might be a defect on latest version

```
Column(children: <Widget>[
        TextFormField(
          onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          onEditingComplete: () => FocusScope.of(context).nextFocus(),
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
        ),
        TextFormField(
          textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
        ),
      ]),
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For some strange reason, `onEditingComplete` solves my problem on the Android emulator but not on DartPad. I'm currently double-checking if there might be some other mistake I have made..

Comment: I don't think it will work on the dart pad, there is an issue with the keyboard there, just run on a real device if works. The problem will be solved. if works, accept the answer so that others can find it useful.

Comment: Thank you. Are you sure there is an issue with DartPad's keyboard? Would you mind adding a link to where you found this problem (or to explain the problem)? If there's an issue with DartPad then I can very gladly mark your answer as accepted, but I should first make sure that there is such an issue, if you don't mind.

Comment: On DartPad when I click it even not open the keyboard sometimes, I cannot provide you official docs for it. But I think if it's working on all real devices then there is no issue. It's an online emulator kind of web portal, so don't just depend on it.